# Display the details of the employees who have been hired after the employee 'Jack' was hired

Tags: sql, select, nested, where-clause

Below is the code to display the details of the employees who have been hired after the employee 'Jack' was hired

All of the information is in a single table.

My query:

```
select e.employee_name, e.hiredate
from employees e 
where e.employee_hiredate > jack.hiredate;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your 'jack' table, you just need a join:

```
select e.employee_name, e.hiredate 
from employees e
join employees jack on jack.employee_name = 'Jack'
where e.employee_hiredate > jack.hiredate;
```

Alternatively you can use a subquery:

```
select e.employee_name, e.hiredate 
from employees e
where e.employee_hiredate > (select hiredate from employees where employee_name = 'Jack');
```

[This article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) may give you a better explanation on how joins work, and [this article](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) will explain a bit about subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from   employees e 
where  convert(date,e.employee_hiredate)  > (select convert(date,e.employee_hiredate) 
                                             from employees 
                                             where employee = 'jack'
                                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to select record comparing with only a particular employee, you can use a sub-query.

In **Oracle**, you can probably do something like:

```
select e.employee_name, e.hiredate
from employees e 
where TRUNC(e.employee_hiredate) > (SELECT TRUNC(HIREDATE) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'Jack');
```